# Change the Foreground Color of List View Selected Item from Code Behind in WP

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to change the foreground color of List View from code behind but i am getting **object reference not set to an instance of object exception**. 
 Here is my Code;

```
var item = listViewTest.SelectedItem;
ListViewItem listViewItem = this.listViewTest.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
listViewItem.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.GreenYellow);

//manually scrolling to the selected item
listViewTest.ScrollIntoView(listViewTest.SelectedItem);
```

As you can see from the code, what i want is to change the **foreground color** to e.g yellow and then scroll to that particular listview item. The scrolling works but the foreground color isn't working and i am getting exception.

#### Update

Here is the item template;

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,9.5">
                        <TextBlock
                            FontFamily="Times New Roman"
                            Text="{Binding Id}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="1"
                            CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True"
                            Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockBlackStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock
                            Text="{Binding FullInfo}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="2"
                            CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True"
                            Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockBlackStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

#### Update 2

Here is the debugger which shows `ContainerFromItem` null
[image]

Comment: How does your *ItemTemplate* look like? I've tried a [simple example project](http://1drv.ms/1qFGYxu) and works without such issues - can you check it? Also maybe it would be easier to implement some *Binding* and change item's property instead of getting its container.

Comment: @Romasz, i updated the question with item template

Comment: @Romasz, what is your sample app name ?

Comment: It's Example81-ListView, when you click the link it should be selected.

Comment: @Romasz i wrote my code inside another xaml view `NavigationHelper_LoadState` coz as view is loaded i want to scroll to that item and highlight it

Comment: It works fine on my end as well.  Only problems is if you select another item in the list that will be Green as well.  The previous SelectedItem will not turn back to normal state.  Do you mind if I provide you a `<Storyboard>` VisualState solution instead?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware but i want to handle it from code behind becuase as the user select an item from first page, the selected item is shown (with color or highlighted) in the second page in `NavigationHelper_LoadStaate` not in `Selection_Changed` event. I tried to manually trigger this event but still not getting and i debug, i got `null` values there.

Comment: can anyone explains the reason for `-1` ?

Comment: Both pages DataBind to exact same ViewModel?  If so you can bind the SelectedItem to the ViewModel as well.  This way both pages will have the same SelectedItem, then apply a VisualState to the selected item then you have it highlight.   If this is not the case, then I don't really know how you setup this project of yours :),  maybe upload a sample to onedrive or filedrive.  good luck

Comment: unfortunately no. They are different view-models. Its like first page lists books chapters with page numbers and if someone select a particular page number (from chapter listing), it navigates to the second page which shows the exact page (came from first page) with all contents inside it and only the first paragraph is highlighted. Anyway thanks i will figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `listViewTest.ContainerFromItem(item)` is returning null is because

1. Container not rendered yet
2. No item found
3. Container Item is not visible in listview yet (maybe you need to scroll to see that item)

### Solution

Before you call `listViewTest.ScrollIntoView(listViewTest.SelectedItem);`

call await `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1);` to let listview to load first. Then only call `scrollToView()`

Another solution is to add the item yourself so you can access the container by `listViewTest.Items[listViewTest.SelectedIndex]` and set the forecolor there

### Edits

To add item manually just loop trough your item and call this method.

```
    private void AddItem(Foo f)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
        TextBlock tb_id = new TextBlock();
        tb_id.Text = f.Id;
        // Set your other proerty here
        sp.Children.Add(tb_id);

        TextBlock tb_fullInfo = new TextBlock();
        tb_fullInfo.Text = f.FullInfo;
        // Set your other property here
        sp.Children.Add(tb_fullInfo);

        lvi.Content = sp;
        listViewTest.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
```

And of course you need to set your other properties like font family and such.

Comment: how to sset color after `listViewTest.Items[listViewTest.SelectedIndex]` ?

Comment: You can just cast that to 'ListViewItem' and set the foreground

Comment: i did so. it does returns the selected item but when i casst it, it returns null `listViewTest.Items[listViewTest.SelectedIndex] as ListViewItem`

Comment: Did you add listviewitem or are you still using item template

Comment: i m using item template

Comment: What I mean by adding item manually is actually adding the UI manually by using listviewitem then placing text block in there then add that listviewitem into the list view.

Comment: No binding at all. Well is a bad way but it solves my problem too

Comment: can you provide a working example i might get some hints from it as i am new to xaml type of apps.

Comment: **NEVER** use Thread.Sleep (or similar) to solve problems related to waiting for something to happen. In this case you should use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke with DispatcherPriority set to e.g. Loaded or lower. Your code will get run only when items are already rendered on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code to change foreground color of selected item

```
private void connecteditems_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem;
        item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
```

Comment: `an instance of object can't be assign variable of type Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem` compiler error. i cast it but still not firing the selection changed event